# Can the Streacom FC8's heat pipes accomodate a Thin-ITX motherboard

Tags: case, mini-pc

I'd like to use an Asus H81T motherboard for my next desktop, and wanted a fanless case for it.  I found the Akasa Euler and Streacom FC8 and the FC8 is the clear winner since it gives me enough room to put 2 disks in the box as well as letting me include an optical drive.

Problem is that looking at Streacom's system-build guide about where the CPU should be placed for FC8's heat-pipes to be usable, I get the impression that the Thin-ITX form used by the H81T puts the CPU too far from the backplate.

Can someone confirm (or deny) that the FC8's heat pipes can be used with a Thin-ITX motherboard such as the H81T?

Alternatively, what other cases would you recommend for a fanless system that can host a Thin-ITX motherboard and with room for an optical drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up asking Streacom (what an idea, eh?) and they confirmed that the FC8 should work fine with Thin-ITX, such as the Asus H81T.

I received my FC8 Alpha and can confirm that it happily accomodates Thin-ITX boards (I'm using an H81T, but Thin-ITX is sufficiently precisely defined that it should work for all Thin-ITX boards).